# Weblogic Error: Connection test failed

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to create a SQL Server 2014 data source in weblogic through admin console. When I click on test configuration, I get the following error:

> Message icon - Error Connection test failed.
>   
> Message icon - Error [FMWGEN][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]
> Could not find stored procedure 'master..xp_jdbc_open2'.

Answer (score 2):

In WebLogic console, if you are selected XA Driver then it need additional drivers  specific library files like sqljdbc.dll etc.
Better to choose Oracle non XA driver(second item from the dropdown list) while you are configuring your datasource.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

That stored procedure isn't installed on SQL Server by default.

Seems like JDBC needs to do some kind of initialization on that server first. Compare the target server with a server where the connection does work - I'll bet you find a difference in some JDBC item in Programs and Features, or hopefully this has already rung a bell about something that had to be configured elsewhere that still needs to be done for this server.

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/deploying-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver16), [this blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brian_swan/getting-started-with-the-sql-server-jdbc-driver), and [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150915213408/https://blogs.oracle.com/vijaya/entry/sqlserver_jdbc_driver_sqlserver_could).